# Node: append output to existing file

Tags: node.js, spawn, tee

I want to append the stdout-output to an existing file. But it overrides it instead. 
Code:
spawn tee...

```
teeForStdout = spawn( 'tee', [ 'pathtologfile' ], {
        detached: true,
        env: process.env,
        stdio: 'pipe'
    });
```

spawn the command...

```
    executedProcess = spawn(command, parameters, {
        detached: true,
        env: process.env,
        stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stdout]
    });
```

try to log the stdout into tee...

```
    executedProcess.stdout.pipe(teeForStdout.stdin);
```

What am I doing wrong?
thx for any help
M.

Answer (score 3):

`tee` will create a new file unless you provide the `-a/--append` option (see the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)).

Instead of spawning `tee` you can also [create a write stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) that will append:

```
var stream = require('fs').createWriteStream('pathtologfile', { flags : 'a' });
// and then later on:
executedProcess.stdout.pipe(stream);
```